# When the coder runs an error appears saying that it is "None Type" object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, pasting

When the coder runs, I get the following error message:

```
“None Type” object has no attribute 'save'
```

The script is as follows:

```
#Image.blend(image1, image2, alpha)

from PIL import Image
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # single use of plt is commented out
import os.path  
import PIL.ImageDraw 

def get_images(directory=None):
    """ Returns PIL.Image objects for all the images in directory.

    If directory is not specified, uses current directory.
        Returns a 2-tuple containing 
    a list with a  PIL.Image object for each image file in root_directory,     and
    a list with a string filename for each image file in root_directory
    """

    if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

    word_images = [] # Initialize aggregaotrs
    pic_list = []
    picture= []
    words= []

    directory_list = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\claudiahurtado\\Documents\\Python Programs\\Project') #     Get list of files
    for entry in directory_list:
        absolute_filename = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\claudiahurtado\\Documents\\Python Programs\\Project', entry)
        #print(absolute_filename)
        try:
            image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename)
            picture += [entry] # i am creating diffrent files one that contains the names of the files and the other that is the pictures
            pic_list += [image]
        except IOError:
            pass

    directory_list2 = os.listdir('C:\\Users\\claudiahurtado\\Documents\\Python Programs\\1.4.5 Images') # Get list of files
    for entry in directory_list2:
        absolute_filename2 = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\claudiahurtado\\Documents\\Python Programs\\1.4.5 Images', entry)
        try:
            image = PIL.Image.open(absolute_filename2)
            words += [entry] # i am creating diffrent files one that contains the names of the files and the other that is the pictures
            word_images += [image]           
        except IOError:
            pass # do nothing with errors tying to open non-images

    return word_images, pic_list, words, picture #returns 3 lists, word_list and pic_list are lists containing the pictures
        #words contains the file names of the list of pictures that are transparent, pictures is a list of the names of the other pictures

def make_poster(img1,img2):
    width, hight= img1.size
    img2.resize((width,hight))
    img1.convert('RGBA')
    img2.convert('RGBA')
    new_image= Image.blend(img1, img2.resize((width,hight)), alpha=.5)
    new_image.show()
    return new_image 

def make_all_poster(directory=None ):
     if directory == None:
        directory = os.getcwd() # Use working directory if unspecified

    # Create a new directory 'modified'
     new_directory = os.path.join(directory, 'modified')
     try:
        os.mkdir(new_directory)
     except OSError:
        pass
     word_imgs, pict_imgs, word_filenames, picture_filenames = get_images()
          number=0
     logo_img = PIL.Image.open('aclu.jpg')
     logo_w, logo_h = logo_img.size
     for x in range(len(pict_imgs)):
        for y in range(len(word_imgs)):
        # Parse the filenamefor n in range(len(image_list)):
        # Parse the filename
            filename, filetype = picture_filenames[x].split('.')

            new_image= make_poster(pict_imgs[x], word_imgs[y])
            w,h = new_image.size

            new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename + str(number)+ '.png')
            new_image.save(new_image_filename)
            number+=1
```

The error stems from around where the new img is made. This is when the code stopped working and started returning an error. For some reason it does not take the new img as a value and will not save it, however if I take out that part and ask it to save new image there is no error.

The problem lies with when I paste the image ontop of new_image.

Comment: When submitting a question like this, please reduce your code to the shortest possible fragment that can will result in the error. If at all possible, make the code self-contained, so that others can run the code themselves. Finally, always provide the actual error traceback, not just your interpretation of what is the most important part of it.

Comment: #save the altered image, suing PNG to retain transparency
    113             new_image_filename = os.path.join(new_directory, filename + str(number)+ '.png')
--> 114             poop_image.save(new_image_filename)
    115             number+=1
    116 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'

Answer (score 0):

It appears that

```
make_poster(pict_imgs[x], word_imgs[y])
```

May return `None`. Which makes `new_image` set to `None`.

That is likely why you get

```
“None Type” object has no attribute 'save'
```

When you do `new_image.save(<...>)`